# Set a cookie only in single posts

Tags: single, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie when a user is on a single post. I'm keeping track of how many single posts he has read this month. I have two problems:

I have a custom template and added the following code to my functions.php

```
function articlesVisited() {
  if (is_single()){
    $postNumber = $wp_query->post->ID;
    setcookie($postNumber,'visited',time()+60*60*24*31);
  }
}
add_action('init', 'articlesVisited');
```

First. The code inside is_single() is never reached when I visit a single post on my site. If I put an -else- block after it, it executes that.

Second, the $wp_query->post->ID does not give me the ID of the post. I think that has something to do with global variables...

Does anyone has experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`init` is too early (it happens before the main query), use the action `template_redirect` instead.

And for the ID use `get_the_ID()`.

Example:

```
if ( is_singular() )
    setcookie( get_the_ID(), 'visited',time() + ( DAY_IN_SECONDS * 31 ) );
```

Comment: Changing to template_redirect helped! Thanks! Also now $wp_query->post->ID works, I used this because get_the_ID() only worked within the Loop if I'm correct.

Comment: @RutgervanWaveren The global post object on a single page is available before you call the loop.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Comment: @Damainman See my update.

Comment: Awesome thanks, and just template_redirect instead of init? Thank you again, I upvoted you.